# Using python to send unsigned char

Tags: python, c, sockets, ctypes

I am doing a project related to cryptography. I am building the code in `python`. But the crypto functions use a C library `PBC` for computations. Hence I have made a C program that contains just the right functions and I have compiled it as a shared library. I import the library using `ctypes`. All has been well so far.

The problem that I face now is that I need to take an `unsigned char` declared as a global variable in the library and I need to send it through the python socket to another receiving python socket, where it will be passed back as an `unsigned char` to the library.

Right now, when I try to retrieve the `unsigned char` from the library,

```
ibc = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libibc.so.1.0.1')
strin = 'some string'
ibc.init_pairing(1, 1, 1)# Initializing the lib
ibc.read_share()
id_str = (c_char * 40)()
id_str.value = strin
ibc.hash_id_s(id_str)    # Passing a char to a function

hsid = (c_ubyte * 1000)()
hsid = c_ubyte.in_dll(ibc, "hid")
ibc.gen_privatekey(hsid, 1, 3) #pass unsigned char to function
```

The last line, ends in a segmentation fault.
So I called the `gen_privatekey` function from c itself, using the following code :

```
int genprkey(){
    unsigned char key[100];
    element_to_bytes(key, pks);
    gen_privatekey(key, 1, 2);
}
```

I then call this function from python using :

```
ibc.genprkey()
```

and the program succeeds.

**PROBLEM**

The above function generates an `unsigned char` which will also be stored in another global variable. I tried to retrieve the variable thus :

```
hsidp = (c_char_p)()
hsidp = c_char_p.in_dll(ibc, "hid")
```

I tried the above code on the python interpreter. When I type :

```
hsidp
```

output is :

```
c_char_p(10598250801977757708)
```

But when I type :

```
hsidp.value
```

I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I suspect that my way of handling the variable is not correct. Once I get the `unsigned char` as a variable in python, I need to send it as a message to another socket that will read it and pass it as an `unsigned char` to the same library.

I don't have an idea how this will be possible. Please help

Comment: Can you just post the signature of the `gen_privatekey` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to access an array in a shared library:

Dummy library:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> import os

>>> open('lib.c', 'w').write(
...   'unsigned char data[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};\n')
>>> ret = os.system('gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.c')
```

Load the library and access a length 4 array of `unsigned char`

```
>>> lib = CDLL('./lib.so')
>>> data = (c_ubyte * 4).in_dll(lib, 'data')
>>> list(data)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Also, `c_char_p` is a pointer, and getting that from the first 4 or 8 bytes of the array will point who knows where and thus likely segfault when you try to dereference it. Plus the first statement below instantiates a pointer that gets deallocated immediately when you reassign `hsidp` in the 2nd statement:

```
hsidp = (c_char_p)()   
hsidp = c_char_p.in_dll(ibc, "hid")
```

Likewise the first line below creates a length 1000 array and throws it away. I don't know why. Then you get a single byte from the library.

```
hsid = (c_ubyte * 1000)()
hsid = c_ubyte.in_dll(ibc, "hid")
```

Do you need a byte or an array of bytes? What length? Or does `gen_privatekey` want a pointer to a null-terminated string?

---

You can use `string_at` to get a Python `str` object:

```
>>> hid = (c_ubyte * 24)(*map(ord, "This is a test."))
>>> string_at(hid, 24)
'This is a test.\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Or you can create a `c_char` array from the buffer (or just use that from the outset instead of a `c_ubyte` array):

```
>>> (c_char * 24).from_buffer(hid).value
'This is a test.'
```

A `c_char` array is more convenient for working with strings because of its `value` and `raw` descriptors that return Python `str` objects. These descriptors also allow you to write a string to the buffer:

```
>>> hid = (c_char * 24)()
>>> hid.value = 'This is a test.'
>>> hid.value
'This is a test.'
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I now made just a minor change, `hid = (c_ubyte * 128).in_dll(ibc, "hid")`. There is no seg fault.

Comment: I also wanted to know how I will be able to write this unsigned char to a string such that I will be able to send it via a socket. The PBC functions generate 128 bit keys. So I must be able to write them into some buffer and send it to another socket.

Comment: I added a couple of examples for getting a string from the array.

Comment: I tried `msg = (c_ubyte * 128).from_buffer(hid)`. I will now try to send it on the network. But how will I be able to read from the string and convert into c_ubyte, so as to pass it into the library.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to read it using the (*map, str) function. Thanks a lot

Comment: If it's at least length 128, you can also use `(c_ubyte * 128).from_buffer_copy(the_string)`. I've also added a `c_char` example that I think is more convenient. Your library doesn't care as long as it gets a string of bytes that's the right size.